# Constructing multidimensional rolling window in R?

Tags: python, r, rolling-computation

I'd like to create a multidimensional rolling window in r. Here is an example that I did in Python using `xarray` library and its [rolling](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.rolling.html) function, which is very intuitive and easy:

```
import xarray as xr 
import numpy as np

data = xr.DataArray(np.arange(0,18).reshape(3,3,2))
print(data)
<xarray.DataArray (dim_0: 3, dim_1: 3, dim_2: 2)>
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 4,  5]],

       [[ 6,  7],
        [ 8,  9],
        [10, 11]],

       [[12, 13],
        [14, 15],
        [16, 17]]])

#Now the constructing the rolling window
win_size = 3     # Window size
data_roll = data.rolling(
    dim_0=win_size, dim_1=win_size, center=True).construct(
    dim_0="new_dim0", dim_1="newdim1")
print(data_roll)
<xarray.DataArray (dim_0: 3, dim_1: 3, dim_2: 2, new_dim0: 3, newdim1: 3)>
array([[[[[nan, nan, nan],
          [nan,  0.,  2.],
          [nan,  6.,  8.]],

         [[nan, nan, nan],
          [nan,  1.,  3.],
          [nan,  7.,  9.]]],


        [[[nan, nan, nan],
          [ 0.,  2.,  4.],
          [ 6.,  8., 10.]],

         [[nan, nan, nan],
          [ 1.,  3.,  5.],
          [ 7.,  9., 11.]]],


        [[[nan, nan, nan],
          [ 2.,  4., nan],
...
```

Note that this function pads the matrix in all dimensions with NAs before rolling.
I looked up a couple of functions in R packages, such as [rollapply](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/zoo/versions/1.8-9/topics/rollapply). Most of these functions and suggested methods are either for applying a function on a 1d or, at best 2d array. However, all I need is the actual windows. I wonder how I can get the same results in R?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the package `reticulate`? If you want something specific in Python, it allows you to use anything in Python in R. Replace the period with the dollar sign, otherwise, it's nearly the same (other than package import).

```
library(reticulate)

np <- import("numpy", convert = F)
xr <- import("xarray", convert = F)
data = xr$DataArray(np$arange(0,18)$reshape(3L,3L,2L))
data

# <xarray.DataArray (dim_0: 3, dim_1: 3, dim_2: 2)>
# array([[[ 0.,  1.],
#         [ 2.,  3.],
#         [ 4.,  5.]],
# 
#        [[ 6.,  7.],
#         [ 8.,  9.],
#         [10., 11.]],
# 
#        [[12., 13.],
#         [14., 15.],
#         [16., 17.]]])
# Dimensions without coordinates: dim_0, dim_1, dim_2
```

Comment: Whoa! This is a cool library and definitely solves many of my problems. However, I wonder if it is possible to do it using pure R.

Comment: Also, I was not able to implement the rolling operation with this package. I get some type of error related to python padding.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I just realized how simple this was to do with just base R. (I feel sheepish!)

```
(data2 <- array(1:18, dim = c(3, 2, 3)))
# , , 1
# 
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    4
# [2,]    2    5
# [3,]    3    6
# 
# , , 2
# 
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    7   10
# [2,]    8   11
# [3,]    9   12
# 
# , , 3
# 
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   13   16
# [2,]   14   17
# [3,]   15   18
#
```

If you weren't aware, encapsulating the entire thing in () will cause it to create the object and print simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure how the answer you provided would lead to the overlapping windows. I just posted a not very elegant code that somehow solves my problem,

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after spending some time I came up with an answer for my specific problem. The function I wrote is just good for a 3d matrix and I think there are better ways to improve it:

```
rolling_win <- function(v,win) {
    # This function pad a 3d matrix and returns the overlapping windows in a list
    # Inputs are: 
        #v: the original matrix
        #win: the window size
    mylist <- c()
    padded_data <- array(numeric(),c(dim(v)[1]+win*2,dim(v)[2]+win*2,dim(v)[3])) # pad data
    padded_data[(win+1):(dim(padded_data)[1]-win),(win+1):(dim(padded_data)[2]-win),]<-v
    counter = 1
    for (i in (1+win):(dim(padded_data)[1]-win)){
        for (j in (1+win):(dim(padded_data)[2]-win)){
            a <- padded_data[(i-win):(i+win),(j-win):(j+win),]
            mylist[[counter]]<-a 
            counter = counter+1
        }
    }
    return(mylist)
}

# lets test it on a simple 3*3*2 matrix
v =  seq(1:18)
dim(v) = c(3,3,2)
win=1  
print(v)

, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   10   13   16
[2,]   11   14   17
[3,]   12   15   18

# Apply the function
windows <- rolling_win(v,win)

#Lets take a look at the first element
windows[1]

, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA    1    4
[3,]   NA    2    5

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   10   13
[3,]   NA   11   14
```

While this function works fine for my case but obviously it is not efficient. In case the matrix is big (millions of elements) then this simply would not work. Numpy in Python uses the [stride](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47417420/padding-numpy-rolling-window-operations-using-strides) concept which is way more efficient. I am new to R and am not sure if R can use same concept or not. Also, the generalizability is another problem here.