# How to apply rolling function when all variables in window from multiple columns are required

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to calculate a rolling statistic that requires all variables in a window from two input columns.

My only solution involves a for loop. Is there a more efficient way, perhaps using Pandas' rolling and apply functions?

```
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import coint


def f(x):
    return coint(x['a'], x['b'])[1]


df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'b': [5, 6, 7, 8]})
df2 = df.rolling(2).apply(lambda x: f(x), raw=False)  # KeyError: 'a'
```

I get KeyError: 'a' because df gets passed to f() one series (column) at a time. Specifying axis=1 sends one row and all columns to f(), but neither approach provides the required set of observations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try rolling, mean and sum:

```
df['result'] = df.rolling(2).mean().sum(axis=1)

   a  b  result
0  1  5     0.0
1  2  6     7.0
2  3  7     9.0
3  4  8    11.0
```

**EDIT**

Adding a different answer based upon new information in the question by OP.

Set up the function.

```
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import coint

def f(x):
    return coint(x['a'], x['b'])
```

Create the data and dataframe:

```
a_data = [1,2,3,4]
b_data = [5,6,7,8]

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a': a_data, 'b': b_data})

   a  b
0  1  5
1  2  6
2  3  7
3  4  8
```

I gather after researching coint that you are trying to pass two rolling arrays to f['a'] and f['b']. The following will create the arrays and dataframe.

```
n=2
arr_a = [df['a'].shift(x).values[::-1][:n] for x in range(len(df['a']))[::-1]]
arr_b = [df['b'].shift(x).values[::-1][:n] for x in range(len(df['b']))[::-1]]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'a': arr_a, 'b': arr_b})
```

n is the size of the rolling window.

```
df1
            a           b
0  [1.0, nan]  [5.0, nan]
1  [2.0, 1.0]  [6.0, 5.0]
2  [3.0, 2.0]  [7.0, 6.0]
3      [4, 3]      [8, 7]
```

Then you can use apply.(f) to send in the rows of arrays.

```
df1.iloc[(n-1):,].apply(f, axis=1)
```

Your output is as follows:

```
1    (-inf, 0.0, [-48.37534, -16.26923, -10.00565])
2    (-inf, 0.0, [-48.37534, -16.26923, -10.00565])
3    (-inf, 0.0, [-48.37534, -16.26923, -10.00565])
dtype: object
```

When I run this I do get an error for perfectly colinear data, but I suspect that will disappear with real data.

Also, I know a purely vecotorized solution might have been faster. I wonder what the performance will be like for this if it what you are looking for?

Hats off to @Zero who really had the solution for [this problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36701099/creating-a-pandas-rolling-window-series-of-arrays).

Comment: Thanks @run-out for your answer. It did solve the problem as originally posted. However, I have updated the question to more accurately describe the problem.

Comment: Thanks @run-out. Interestingly, comparing the performance of your solution and the vectorised approach (suggested in your SO link) did not yield a significant difference.

Answer (score 0):

I tried placing the sum before the rolling:

```
import pandas as pd
import time
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'b': [5, 6, 7, 8]})
df2 = df.copy()
s = time.time()
df2.loc[:, 'mean1'] = df.sum(axis = 1).rolling(2).mean()
print(time.time() - s)
s = time.time()
df2.loc[:, 'mean2'] = df.rolling(2).mean().sum(axis=1)
print(time.time() - s)
df2
0.003737926483154297
0.005460023880004883
a   b   mean1   mean2
0   1   5   NaN 0.0
1   2   6   7.0 7.0
2   3   7   9.0 9.0
3   4   8   11.0    11.0
```

It is slightly faster than the previous answer, but works the same and maybe in large datasets the difference migth significant.

You can modify it to select the columns of interest only:

```
s = time.time()
print(df[['a', 'b']].sum(axis = 1).rolling(2).mean())
print(time.time() - s)

0     NaN
1     7.0
2     9.0
3    11.0
dtype: float64
0.0033559799194335938
```