# How to use Pandas vector methods based on rolling custom function that involves entire row and prior data

Tags: pandas

While its easy to use pandas rolling method to apply standard formulas, but i find it hard if it involves multiple column with limited past rows. Using the following code to better elaborate: -

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#create dummy pandas
df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':np.arange(0,25),'col2':np.arange(100,125),'col3':np.nan})

def func1(shortdf):
    #dummy formula 
    #use last row of col1 multiply by sum of col2
    return (shortdf.col1.tail(1).values[0]+shortdf.col2.sum())*3.14

for idx, i in df.iterrows():
    if idx>3:
        #only interested in the last 3 rows from position of dataframe
        df.loc[idx,'col3']=func1(df.iloc[idx-3:idx])
```

I currently use this iterrow method which needless to say is extremely slow. can anyone has better suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1

So [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) is the solution here. You do have to use rolling for the summation, and then shift that series after the addition and multiplication.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':np.arange(0,25),'col2':np.arange(100,125),'col3':np.nan})

ans = ((df['col1'] + df['col2'].rolling(3).sum()) * 3.14).shift(1)
```

You can check to see that `ans` is the same as `df['col3']` by using `ans.eq(df['col3'])`. Once you see that all but the first few are the same, just change `ans` to `df['col3']` and you should be all set.

### Option 2

Without additional information about the customized weight function, it is hard to help. However, this option may be a solution as it separates the rolling calculation at the cost of using more memory.

```
# df['col3'] = ((df['col1'] + df['col2'].rolling(3).sum()) * 3.14).shift(1)

s = df['col2']

stride = pd.DataFrame([s.shift(x).values[::-1][:3] for x in range(len(s))[::-1]])
res = pd.concat([df, stride], axis=1)

# here you can perform your custom weight function
res['final'] = ((res[0] + res[1] + res[2] + res['col1']) * 3.14).shift(1)
```

`stride` is adapted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36701099/creating-a-pandas-rolling-window-series-of-arrays) question and the calculation is concatenated row-wise to the original dataframe. In this way each column has the value needed to compute whatever it is you may need.

`res['final']` is identical to option 1's `ans`

Comment: that works. question, why shift(0) after sum? it doesnt seems to do anything. second question, if i dont want to do some, i want something like ols on past x rows, how do i apply it after rolling?

Comment: sorry for my unclear question, i mean if i dont want to do SUM but do OLS instead.

Comment: As for the `.shift(0)` you are correct and I have edited the answer. When you say OLS do you mean Ordinary Least Squares?

Comment: yes, because for myself, i have a customised Weight Least Square function that i use to predict values, so i trying to see if i can use that

Comment: I added the second option which is more flexible, if the list comprehension is too slow, it may be better to take a look at the second answer provided in the link (use numpy broadcasting, may be faster). Hope this works.